# Imacros random wait time between lower and higher limit

Tags: time, wait, imacros

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://mafiamatrix.com/income/earn.asp
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:earning.asp ATTR=ID:Streetfight
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:earning.asp ATTR=NAME:B1
Wait Seconds = 181
```

I would like for the wait seconds time to be a random value between 180 to 190 seconds

Answer (score 1):

```
SET rndSecWait EVAL("180 + Math.floor(Math.random()*11)")
WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}
```

(This wait includes 180 and 190 seconds.)